# Two possible answers for α and β

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

So there was this limits question in the JEE Main 2022 exam:

If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}( \sqrt{n^{2}-n-1}+n\alpha +\beta)=0$

Find $8(\alpha + \beta)$

It had the following options:

A. 4
B. -8
C. 8
D. -4

I tried to solve it by multiplying the numerator and denominator of the L.H.S. with the conjugate of the numerator and got the following expression:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n^{2}(1-\alpha^{2})-n(1+2\alpha\beta)-(1+\beta^{2})}{\sqrt{n^{2}-n-1}-(n\alpha+\beta)})$

Now since $n$ is tending to infinity and the limit is equal to zero the power of $n$ will be more in the denominator than in the numerator, hence we can equate the coefficients of $n^{2}$ and $n$ in the numerator to zero which gives us
$1=\alpha^{2}$
and $-1=2\alpha\beta$
so there are two possible $(\alpha,\beta)$: $(1,\frac{-1}{2})$ and $(-1,\frac{1}{2})$
for which there are two possible answers to $8(\alpha+\beta):4$ and $-4$

But there is only one correct answer to the question: $-4$

What is wrong with my reasoning and solution?

Comment: You've created a spurious solution because you've introduced squaring, I think. I'll have to think about that a bit. ¶ Incidentally, it might be easier just to say something like $\sqrt{n^2-n-1} \sim -\alpha n - \beta$ (as $n \to \infty$) and figure it out that way.

Comment: Yeah, I think basically, you've taken $f(n)+g(n)$, and made $\frac{[f(n)]^2-[g(n)]^2}{f(n)-g(n)}$ out of it. Since you're focusing on the numerator, you'll get essentially two solutions: one where $f(n) \sim g(n)$, and one where $f(n) \sim -g(n)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that $n^2-n-1=(n-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{5}{4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers actually addresses why your method does not seem to work. I will show you how your method can be saved.

Firstly, you find out that the limit is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ with $a_n:=n^{2}(1-\alpha^{2})-n(1+2\alpha\beta)-(1+\beta^{2})$ and $b_n:=\sqrt{n^{2}-n-1}-(n\alpha+\beta)$. This is correct!

Now, you want $a_n$ to be asymptotically weaker than $b_n$, which actually requires $a_n$ to be a constant, that is,

$$1-\alpha^2=0,\qquad 1+2\alpha\beta=0.$$

**However**, notice that this condition is not enough: If $b_n$ tends to a constant as well, then $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ tends towards a non-zero constant, and your limit is not zero. Thus, we need to add the condition that $\alpha\neq 1$.

In total, we end up with a system
$$1-\alpha^2=0,\qquad 1+2\alpha\beta=0,\qquad\alpha\neq 1,$$

which means that $\alpha=-1$ and $\beta=\frac 12$.

Comment: I understand that $b_n$ should not tend towards a constant as it makes the limit a non-zero constant. But how did you conclude that $b_n$ would only be a constant if $\alpha$ would be 1? Is it not possible for $b_n$ to be constant for any other value of $\alpha$?

Comment: @HimanshuSingh Notice that $\sqrt{n^2-n-1}=n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}$, and so it behaves asymptotically like $n$ (because the root tends towards $1$).

Comment: I understand it completely. Thank you so much. @Zuy

Answer (score 2):

I assume $n\to+\infty$ so
$$
\sqrt{n^2 - n - 1} = n\sqrt{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}}
$$
therefore
$$
\sqrt{n^2 - n - 1} + \alpha n +\beta
=n\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}} +\alpha\right)+\beta
$$
therefore necessarily one has
$$
\alpha = -1
$$
in fact any value of $\alpha$ different from $-1$ makes the limit $\infty$. Now
\begin{align*}
n\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}} -1\right)
&=n\frac{\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}} -1\right)\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}} +1\right)}{\sqrt{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}} +1}\\
&=n\frac{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}-1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac1n - \frac1{n^2}} +1}\to-\frac12
\end{align*}
hence $\beta=\frac12$ which leads to $8(\alpha + \beta)=-4$.